# Potentiometer "US 250KA" same as 250k?

Tags: potentiometer

I want to replace the potentiometers in my electrical bass due to scratching. All three of them (volume of pickup 1, volume 2, tone) are of the same kind, "**US 250KA**" single-turn (no push/pull).

Is this regular **250K**, or does the "**US**" or the "**KA**" stand for something special?

I don't want to change anyting, I just want to put the instrument into its originla (non-scratchy) state.

Comment: Besides the ohms range, what you need to know is the allowed power dissipation and whether its log or linear, and iirc linear is B and log is A

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think the dissipation doesn't need to be very high here, for guitar pickups generate very small currencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a regular 250K ohm potentiometer but the "**A**" tells that it is **logarithmic** while the "**B**" tells that the potentiometer is **linear**.

Now you have to know if your system needs a logarithmic potentiometer or a linear one.

Our ear perceive sound on a logarithmic scale so there are chances that you need a logarithmic one since you want to change the volume.

Comment: Logarithmic makes sense in guitars. I just didn't guess "A" standing for logarithmic. Thanks a lot.